# Translation of "辨人禽界，立天地心"

Tags: translation

I am working on the translation of a Chinese text and I'm stuck with this expression: "辨人禽界，立天地心". I think it means something like "recognize the human (bird?) world, and establishing/building heaven and earth".

I often see 为天地立心，为生民立命， 为往圣继绝学，为万世开太平 as well. Thanks for telling me what this may mean too. I heard it was used by 张载 and wish to grasp its true meaning.

If someone has an idea of its precise meaning, please let me know. I wish I could make sure of it for me to deeply understand what this article is about and make the whole translation accurate.

Comment: the verse is, like federation flag, might be controversial. so, may i ask, "辨人禽界立天地心" is in what context? it's meaning would be ranged from "as is", "han-chinese-supremacy", to "non-han-chinese-hostile".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally had this as a comment but it seems like it has become an answer.

---

Confucianism likes to talk about the separation of man (人) and beast (禽), so that would be the crux of the first sentence, i.e.: separating the human and animal worlds.

立天地心 should be talking about setting a standard or a principle for heaven and earth, there are many translations that put similar ideas as: ordaining a conscience for Heaven and Earth.

---

In relation to your edit:

There are a couple of well-known translations for 为天地立心，为生民立命， 为往圣继绝学，为万世开太平

> To ordain conscience for Heaven and Earth
>     To secure life and fortune for the people
>     To continue lost teachings for past sages
>     To establish peace for all future generations

another would be:

> To ordain conscience for Heaven and Earth
>     To secure life and fortune for the populace
>     To carry on lost teachings of ancient sages
>     To build peace for posterity

Comment: Thanks. Could we say then "raise your consciousness for Heaven and Earth" ? It seems proper since there's also a distinction between Men and beasts, right ? Would you mind elaborating about 为天地立心，为生民立命， 为往圣继绝学，为万世开太平 too ?

Comment: Thanks for the translations of 为天地立心，为生民立命， 为往圣继绝学，为万世开太平 :)

Comment: @Mat 立心 is defined as 树立准则 in《汉语大词典》: 树立+准则 is a simple combo of set-up & standard, does that equate to `raise your consciousness`, probably not?

Comment: So what do you mean by "ordain conscience" ? I don't get the use of "ordain"... I don't understand this "To ordain conscience for Heaven and Earth"

Comment: This isn’t my translation, and it is, albeit, quite archaic but you can understand *ordain* as establish or enact.

Comment: Beautiful translate!

Answer (score 1):

辨人禽界，立天地心

Simple translation:

天地 = natural world, people and society = 天下

辨人禽界，= 辨别人和禽兽的界限，
distinguish the boundaries between people and animals
立天地心 = become a good person

Have a look [here:](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/584654466517858445.html)

"其实，“为天地立心”是指为社会建立一套以“仁”、“孝”等道德伦理为核心的精神价值系统。 “立心”也就是“立天理”之心，因为天理“能使天下悦且通”，从而使“天下”（社会）必然会普遍接受仁孝之理等道德价值。“为天地立心”的涵义其重点不在认识论，而在价值论。"